# How to Instantiate a List with a List of new objects

Tags: c#

The following code works.

```
List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>()
{
    new Card("SA"), 
    new Card("HA"), 
    new Card("CA"), 
    new Card("DA"), 
    new Card("SK"), 
    new Card("S2"), 
    new Card("D2") 
};
```

I would like to reduce the clutter so I'm looking for some thing like this

```
List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>() 
{ 
    new Card() 
    { 
        "SA", "HA", "CA", "DA", "SK", "S2", "D2"
    }
};
```

I swear. I saw it somewhere but I just can't define it properly to google the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
var codes = new string [] { "SA", "HA", "CA", "DA", "SK", "S2", "D2" };
var cards = codes.Select( code => new Card(code) ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

*Just to extend answers from others*

If `Card` class has a type conversion operator like this:

```
class Card
{
    public Card(string str)
    { }

    // This one converts string to Card.
    public static implicit operator Card(string str)
    {
        return new Card(str);
    }
}
```

Then you could do the following which looks close to what you got in question:

```
var list = new List<Card> { "SA", "HA", "CA", "DA", "SK", "S2", "D2" };
```

Answer (score 3):

In `C# 6` you can use [Extension Add methods in collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#extension-add-methods-in-collection-initializers):

```
public static class CardListExtensions
{
   public static void Add(this List<Card> list, string name)
   {
      list.Add(new Card(name));
   }
}
```

After adding such extension method you will be able to use it in collection initializer:

```
List<Card> list = new List<Card> {"SA", "HA", "CA"};
```

Comment: Hey, I didn't know you could do that! Cool trick! This works just as well as the implicit operator answer, and is less [astonishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)..

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a shorter code, how about this

```
"SA_HA_CA_DA_SK_S2_D2".Split("_").Select(x => new Card(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: I would actually recommend this over another answer, except maybe reconsider _ as a separator and use semicolon instead. Why? Because it's much easier to put this in config. Or pass around as params, or debug. So the above code can be reused. Much more difficult to maintain arrays. Including error handling, null handling and such. I upvoted.